# Double definite integral $ I= \int_{-\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 2} dx \int_{-\sqrt{2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}} (x^2+ y^2) \sqrt{(1+x^2+ y^2)} dy $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$ I= \int_{-\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 2} dx \int_{-\sqrt{2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}} (x^2+ y^2) \sqrt{(1+x^2+ y^2)} dy $$
Let $1+x^2+y^2=u$, then $ du = 2 dy $. Do the integral of the $y$ part first:
$$ \frac12 \int (u-1) \sqrt u\ du = \frac12\int( u^\frac32 - u^{\frac12})\ du = \frac12 \int (\frac25u^\frac52 - \frac23u^\frac32)du $$ the definite integral result of $y$ part is:
$$ \frac25 (1+x^2+y^2)^\frac52\bigg |_{-\sqrt{2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}} = 0 $$
similarly, $ -\frac23 \int u^\frac32 du =0 $
Finally, the $I = 0$.

Where is wrong?

Comment: I don't know what went wrong, but this feels like it's *begging* to be converted into polar coordinates.

Comment: What seems to be wrong is $1+x^2+y^2=u\implies du=2dy$

Comment: Cylindrical coordinates make the solution easier. But what's the correct result of $ du $?

Comment: $1+x^2+y^2=u$, $du=2ydy$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're doing some multivariate integration. In that case, for something like this, it would be wise to convert some of those coordinates from Cartesian coordinates to Cylindrical coordinates.

You know that $x^2+y^2=r^2$, so $\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2} = \sqrt{1+r^2}$. Since your first integrand has bounds from $-a$ to $a$, you can also convert that from $0$ to $2\pi$ as your radians. Your bounds for your second integrand would be 0 to $\sqrt{2}$ because that is the radius of integration.

So your final double integral is one integral from $0$ to $2\pi$ and the second integral from $0$ to $\sqrt{2}$ of $r^2\sqrt{1+r^2}r dr d\theta$

The reason why you have an extra $r$ in front of $drd\theta$ is because you converted to Cylindrical coordinates.